# What's wrong with my data submisson system[one button, 2 fields]

Tags: php, forms

I am setting up my custom blog's basic submission system.

This is the PHP section of it that I try to submit the inserted data into the database

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();
    }
    include('../includes/db_connect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $newTitle = $_POST['newTitle'];
        $newPost = $_POST['newPost'];
        $my_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        if(!empty($newPost))
            if(!empty($newTitle)){
        $sql="INSERT INTO posts  (title, body)
    VALUES($newTitle, $newPost)";
        $query = $db->query($sql);
        if($query){
                echo "Post entered to database";
            }else{
                echo "Error Submitting the data";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Then There is the submission form, I am pretty sure this is the faulty end for some reason, but I cannot find out why.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"name="newTitle" method="post">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
                    <p>Title:</p><br><input type="text" name="newTitle">
                    <textarea name="newPost" cols="110" rows="25"/></textarea><br>
                    <label for="newPost">Add New Post</label><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
                        </form>
```

This is the database's table:

```
post_id (A_I)
user_id
title
body
category_id
posted(datetime)
```

Bear in mind that I am a rookie in this area, so don't be too harsh :)

Comment: Why you have two `form` tags next to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote for strings:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO posts (title, body) VALUES ('$newTitle', '$newPost')";
                                            //^         ^  ^        ^
```

**Notice:**
Try to use `PDO` and `param binding` in your projects to prevent sql injection.

[Nice Tutorial about PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Comment: It's the little things.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use single form tag only:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
                    <p>Title:</p><br><input type="text" name="newTitle">
                    <textarea name="newPost" cols="110" rows="25"/></textarea><br>
                    <label for="newPost">Add New Post</label>
                     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
               </form>
```

And in your php code, you can check youe data by using isset() function

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_POST['newTitle']) && ($_POST['newPost']))
        $newTitle = $_POST['newTitle'];
        $newPost = $_POST['newPost'];
        $my_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $sql="INSERT INTO posts  (title, body)
    VALUES('$newTitle', '$newPost')";  //use variable in single quote.
        $query = $db->query($sql);
        if($query){
                echo "Post entered to database";
            }else{
                echo "Error Submitting the data";
        }

    }
```